# How can I increase the success of "window.OnBeforeUnload" to send an Ajax ping?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, fire-and-forget

I've read dozens of questions and answers on S.O., and none of them answer my particular question... most of them center around popping up a "Oooh, you need to save" message... that is not my need.

I am building an application for internal use at my office (not a public website), and one "page" in particular we would like to log the 'exiting' by the user.

So, I have this simple statement:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.post('LogExit.aspx');
}
```

Now, this `post` will fail most of the time due to the browser not "wanting" to start a new request since it knows that the page is going away... but, if I add an annoying `alert` box, then it will send the ping 100% of the time!!!

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.post('LogExit.aspx');
    alert("Ha ha ha, I can delay the browser!");
}
```

**So, my question is... how do I ensure (or at least increase the chances of having) the "LogExit.aspx" ping going through?**

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. I think a common strategy is to use `window.open` to open another window that sends the request and closes itself, but popup blockers would thwart that. Maybe you could try sending a synchronous Ajax request...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no 100%, or even 10% "guaranteed" way of achieving this... so, I was able to solve my particular needs by having an `every-10-seconds-send-a-ping` function.

Since my need was to log how long a person was viewing a particular page, this work-around above helps to at least get it down to a 10 second window of accuracy.

I really hope a better solution comes down the pipe in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to make some kind of request and don't really care about about the response, you can use an image in this case:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   var img= new Image();
   img.src = "LogExit.aspx";
   // you have to check on your server to see if it worked :)
}
```

Comment: If this works reliably in many different browsers, it's pretty clever.